# API description not show in Swagger UI

Tags: java, spring, api, spring-mvc, swagger

I want to documenting a REST API with Swagger and Spring MVC,

I explore /api-docs URL in Swagger UI

Just like below image.

[image]

[image]

Have anyone can help me solve two question?

```
1. I don't know why the description isn't display.
2. how can I show all API in same group
```

SwaggerConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger
public class SwaggerConfig {
  private SpringSwaggerConfig springSwaggerConfig;

  @Autowired
  public void setSpringSwaggerConfig(SpringSwaggerConfig springSwaggerConfig){
      this.springSwaggerConfig = springSwaggerConfig;
  }

  @Bean
  public SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin customImplementation(){
    return new SwaggerSpringMvcPlugin(this.springSwaggerConfig)
      .apiInfo(apiInfo())
      .includePatterns(".*/rest.*");
    }

  private ApiInfo apiInfo(){
      ApiInfo apiInfo = new ApiInfo(
      "API description", "API for me", 
      "API terms of service", 
      "ageehuang@gmail.com", "", ""
      );
      return apiInfo;
    }
```

pom.xml

```
jackson-annotations 2.2.3
jackson-databind 2.2.3
jackson-core 2.2.3
guava 14.0
swagger-springmvc 1.0.2
swagger-core_2.10 1.3.7
```

ServletConifg

```
.......
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"config.swagger"})
public class ServletConfig{ 
.......
```

Controller.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/v1")
@Api(value = "CounponController" ,description="SCCCCCC")
public class CouponController {
........
```

http://localhost:8080/coupon/api-docs

```
{"apiVersion":"1.0","apis":[{"description":"SCCCCCC","path":"/default/counponcontroller","position":0},{"description":"Coupon Order Controller","path":"/default/coupon-order-controller","position":0},{"description":"Data Controller","path":"/default/data-controller","position":0},{"description":"Ep Controller","path":"/default/ep-controller","position":0}],"authorizations":{},"info":{"contact":"ageehuang@eztravel.com.tw","description":"API for Ez-Conpon","license":"","licenseUrl":"","termsOfServiceUrl":"EzTravel API terms of service","title":"EzTravel"},"swaggerVersion":"1.2"}
```

If need any information , please tell me

I will be grateful for any help you can provide.

Comment: Did you got any solution for this. I am facing same problem

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about Spring-MVC take on Swagger, but I hope you could use [my research on Swagger 1.5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34883784/3990817) to shed a watery light on your situation. I used your questions (and shared your shared image) to build up mine, so I'm sure it can provide you with partial assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the first question its because your using the wrong swagger-core dependency. Try using the following dependency `com.wordnik:swagger-annotations:1.3.11` (gradle artifact representation)

Will post in detail about the second question in a bit

Comment: I am facing same problem. and I have tried by adding same dependency as mentioned by you, but my problem is not solved.