# Swagger 1.5 Doesn't Display My 1.2's @Api Description?

Tags: java, dropwizard, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I recently upgraded a project from Swagger API 1.2 to 2.0 (or, speaking in Swagger-core terms, from 1.3 to 1.5). Because of their excellent [migration guide](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/1.3--1.5-Migration), I managed to do that in a very short time and almost without a hitch. The only thing that is bugging me is the lack of support for the `@Api` annotation's `description` value. The endpoints were meticulously documented - up to and including the top-level API endpoints - but their descriptions ceased to be showed in the UI:

[image: example]
Notice that something's missing?

Some research (meaning, reading the source code) yielded that the same `description`s are now obsolete, making room for fancier `@Tag` annotations. But I couldn't find information on how to apply them so the descriptions would still be in each endpoint class.

Using just Dropwizard, is there a way to programmatically make this happen in Swagger 1.5?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to eventually solve the issue by understanding a couple of concepts:

1. API endpoints (that usually have the `@Api` annotation) [are grouped by Tag, not by resource](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/wiki/swagger-1.2-to-2.0-migration-guide#whats-new). This can make, for example, an operation be listed under more than one category. Tags can, but not have to, be derived from the `value` attribute of the `@Api` annotation – the one that usually starts with a slash. This makes the grouping, and hence the UI, behave almost the same when migrating, but also caused me the confusion of not realizing the `description` attribute is ignored – *something* must be reading that, right?
2. Tags are first-class citizens in Swagger's specs ([see here](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/wiki/swagger-1.2-to-2.0-migration-guide#operationGrouping)). They are extensible and can have descriptions, as mentioned in [this comment](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/578#issuecomment-76096593).
3. One can add tags or [enhance existing ones](http://swagger.io/customizing-your-auto-generated-swagger-definitions-in-1-5-x/) by programmatically apply the [`@Tag` annotation](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/blob/master/modules/swagger-annotations/src/main/java/io/swagger/annotations/Tag.java) to *any* resource discoverable by Swagger. Just pick a resource and list the desired descriptions there – but be sure to have them in only one place. Lucky for me, I happen to have an abstract class all the resources extend. So it was possible for me to write the descriptions in the most natural place, given the circumstances:

   ```java
   import io.swagger.annotations.Contact;
   import io.swagger.annotations.Info;
   import io.swagger.annotations.SwaggerDefinition;
   import io.swagger.annotations.Tag;
   ```

   and then

   ```java
   @SwaggerDefinition(
     info = @Info(
       title = "My API",
       version = "0.1",
       contact = @Contact(name = "Me", email = "me@myself.com")
     ),
     tags = {
      @Tag(
        name = "pets", description = "Manage pets"
      ), @Tag(
        name = "search", description= "Search pets"
      ), ...
     }
   )
   public class BaseResource {
   ...
   }
   ```

Voila! The old-new descriptions can be exhibited after compiling and firing up the UI, just like one can see at the aforementioned [comment](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/578#issuecomment-76096593). Achievement unlocked.

To really seal the deal, one can now delete `@Api`'s `description` attribute from your resources, as the description is inferred from the `@Tag` specifications.