# Swagger-ui version 2.1.4 is not populating API list grouping on Controllers

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I moved from swagger 1.x to 2.x , now the swagger-ui is not populating the API's in Controller group.

Example:
Suppose I have three Controllers ( we are using Spring MVC)

1. ABCController with its base url mapping "abc/test1" and @API(value="ABCController" )
2. XYZController with its base url mapping "xyz/test2" and @API(value="XYZController" )
3. ABCXYZController with its base url mapping "abc/test3" and @API(value="ABCXYZController" )

Now , when I start my application

It shows four API Listing (but with API url instead of @Api tag value) ,

1. abc/
2. abc/test1
3. xyz/test2
4. abc/test3

but I wanted to have only 3 Listings ( Grouping with controller and @Tag value property.

1. XyzController
2. ABCController
3. ABCXYZController

Answer (score 0):

there is a concept of tags in swagger.  When one is not provided, it will be deduced from the `@Api` annotation.

Try setting the annotation like such:

```
@Api(value="ABCController, tags = "ABCController" )
```

Comment: @MishraJi, perhaps you should try setting the `@Tag` annotation on your controller, as I wrote [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34883784/3990817).